# My crawler from beautifulsoup is not writing the content of the webpage anymore

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have written a web crawling code to collect the data from Waze live map. It used to work and successfully wrote down the content of the response on a text file. However, now the only output it will save in the text file is " 'b' " value. It seems it cannot access the content of the webpage. I have added the headers before because the link I am using is a RSS feed of the page. Here is my code:

```
# Extract the object from Waze live map
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import requests


class AppURLOpener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
  version = "Mozilla/5.0"

def event (left, right, bottom, up):

link = "https://www.waze.com/rtserver/web/TGeoRSS?ma=600&mj=100&mu=100&left="+ left + "&right=" + right + "&bottom=" + bottom + "&top=" + \
       up + "&_=1504116242156"
print (link)
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(link)
rs = r.content
print (rs)
soup = BeautifulSoup(rs, 'html.parser')
soup2 = soup.encode('UTF-8')
content = str(soup2)
with open("I-5 LA.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(content)
```

I do not receive any error, the problem is that the content of the JSON response is not being written in the text file anymore.Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. Please fix it. Where do you call the `event()` function and what arguments do you pass?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason is this url from waze is not public anymore.  See below. I also am trying to access but will discuss and see if can get feed access through partner plan.

https://support.google.com/waze/partners/answer/7239095?hl=en
https://www.waze.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=249944

> Postby bedo2991 » Sun Feb 11, 2018 7:45 pm
>
> Waze disabled all requests to GeoRSS feed, with the exception of
>   interface tokens. Get in contact with your Global Champs in case you
>   need access to it for something useful to the whole community.